# Re-ordering an item within a list in a hibernate many-many association

Tags: hibernate, collections, associations

I have two entities Person and Preference. There is a many-many relationship between the two.
The person and preference relationships are stored in a mapping table

```
CREATE TABLE `person_2_preference` (
`person_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`preference_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`sort_order` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`person_id`,`preference_id`);
```

A person has an ordered list of preferences as shown below.

```
<list  name="preferences" table="person_2_preference" lazy="true" inverse="false" 
        cascade="save-update">
            <key column="person_id" update="false"/>
            <index column="sort_order"/>
            <many-to-many class="com.xx.Preference" column="preference_id" />
        </list>
```

In the java class, i would like to reorder the preferences in some cases, so i am doing a Collections.swap like
Collections.swap(person.getPreferences(), index, index++) ( I have validations to make sure the indices are not out of range)

When i save the person - personDao.saveOrUpdate(person), i am getting a unique constraint violation exception because of the primary keys.

I have other ordered relationships that are one-many and the re-order using Collections.swap works great.Is this a limitation on a many-many relationship? Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue comes from the internal storage structure of Hibernate, which gets confused by your swap. Hibernate also stores the objects of your list in a first level cache, and it has somewhere stored the values which are actually in the database so it can decide if an update is necessary or not.

When you change the order in the list, then there are two ways how to update: Either you let person_id and preference_id unchanged and modify sort_order, or you let the sort_order unchanged and modify person_id and preference_id. In the case of a swap the second way results in a unique constraint violation after the first of the two updates. By some reasons, which have to do with the internal organisation of Hibernate, Hibernate does the update in the second way.

There are (at least) three different possibilities how to solve the problem:

1. You add a serial to the table person_2_preference and make this serial the primary key (Hibernate loves primary keys with only one single column). I didn't test this, I'm not 100% sure if it will solve your problem.
2. You do the updates manually by the HQL update statement:

   `UPDATE Person2Preference SET sortOrder= :order WHERE personId=:person and preferenceId=:preference`

   Person2Perference is the class mapped to the person_2_preference. This has to be done for every child object. After this an `evict()` of the parent object and/or the child objects might be recommendable (Hibernate does not update the first level cache after this update).
3. You do not swap elements in the list which you got as a result from Hibernate. You copy this list into an array list (or into an array) and you do the swap only in the copy. This does not need much memory, because in your copy there are only references to the objects. In the Hibernate objects you only do the update of the sort order.

I probably would do solution 3. Solution 1 I would do if there were any other need for the new serial.

Comment: Thanks for the response, dont i need to do #2 to effective do #3? Because to update the sort_order i need a class mapped to the mapping table. I am trying to avoid mapping a class to this many2many table because that table does not have any other columns

Comment: You don't need #2 for doing #3. In #2 you use the HQL update statement, in #3 you just update the parent object, i. e. the `Person` instance. But you're right, for both #2 and #3 (and perhaps even #1) you need a class which is mapped to the person_2_preference table. I thought you already had that class. Nevertheless, I would introduce that class, because it provides the flexibility to you which you need here. It is not much work to create this simple class.

Comment: I had the same problem, and solution (1) fixed it.  Thanks!